# How to search first element in array in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to search an object on only the first element in an array and ignore the rest.
For example, for data below if I wanted to only search the `model` for the first element in the `vehicle` array.

```
{
  "drivers" : [
    {
        "last_name" : "McQueen",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "last_name" : "Buzz",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I know I can do a nested query like this but the problem here is that all the vehicles are searched. I only want the 0th element in the vehicle list to be searched and the rest to be ignored.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "driver",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "driver.vehicle",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "drivers.vehicle.model": "Canyonero" } }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally I want something like `{ drivers.vehicle[0].model": "Canyonero" }` to search for the first vehicle in the list everytime. Is there any way I can effectively do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948351/8160318) -- doing this is certainly possible but quite onerous.

I'd instead recommend using

- [ingest pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404331/8160318) whereby the first vehicle will be extracted to a new root-level field or
- [updating by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-example) where you do the same as above but execute at will as opposed to only upon ingest.