# How to create a range query on array

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

Here is the result of the query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_source": {
            "AR_UnitePoids": 3,
            "CatTarif": [
              {
                "PVTTCSite": 1
              },
              {
                "PVTTCSite": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "_source": {
            "AR_UnitePoids": 5,
            "CatTarif": [
              {
                "PVTTCSite": 3
              },
              {
                "PVTTCSite": 4
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I want to get documents with `AR_UnitePoids` >= 5, I can do:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "AR_UnitePoids": {
        "gte": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "hits": [
        {
          "_source": {
            "AR_UnitePoids": 5,
            "CatTarif": [
              {
                "PVTTCSite": 3
              },
              {
                "PVTTCSite": 4
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But now I want all documents where the second `PVTTCSite` of `CatTarif` is higher than 4:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "CatTarif.1.PVTTCSite": {
        "gte": 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this query doesn't work, I get 0 `hits`.

How can I do this ?

### Edit:

Thank to @TusharShahi comment and this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) I managed to create this query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "CatTarif",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "range": { "CatTarif.PVTTCSite": { "gte": 4 } } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which works but I still can't query on a specific index of the CatTarif.

Comment: Please add index. Is the CarTarif field a nested field? Because if not then it is not possible. Normal objects are flattened in ES

Comment: @TusharShahi, what do you mean by "add index" ? Yes CatTarif is a nested field

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948351/4800344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```json
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "CatTarif",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "range": {
              "CatTarif.PVTTCSite": {
                "gte": 4
              }
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "CatTarif.CatTarif": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```